# Error message when loading GeoPandas package

Tags: python, unicode, runtime-error, geopandas, python-unicode

I've been using GeoPandas until yesterday, but today when I tried to load it just using `import geopandas as gpd` I got the following error message (repeated 20 times):

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 80: invalid continuation byte
```

If I run the cell again, I don't get the error message, however every time I run a cell using geopandas I got the message again, although the command works.

*Edit*: Traceback[image]

Comment: could you share the full traceback?

Comment: @LichKing sure! I've just included it